# How to unlock the comma button instead of dot, when I have the DecimalNumberPad type set

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I have Delphi 10.3.1

For the TEdit object, I have set "DecimalNumberPad" for the field KeyboardType.

On Android I see active only buttons with NUMBERS and DOT. 
The button with the comma is inactive.

How can I set active button with comma instead of dot ?

Comment: Which device is this happening on? Have you tried more than one?

Comment: I have samsung s10. I checked your advice on A3 (2017) and here ONLY the number button appears. There is no comma and dot at all.
I need a keyboard to enter the value of the receipt

Comment: For what it's worth, on both my Nexus 5X and Samsung Tab A 8, the comma is present, and enabled. You might want to try a Java-based app to see if it behaves the same, because from here it looks device specific